# In Silverlight does DateTime get affected if the client-side CPU is overclocked?

Tags: c#, silverlight, cpu

In an Silverlight application, if the client-side CPU is overclocked, would the DateTime structure return the correct time?

Comment: To clear up confusion, can you change either the title or your post, so that you're asking the same question, and not the opposite one! Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The real-time clock is not affected by CPU clocking.

On computers without RTCs, this may have been an issue.  Not anymore.

(It does sound like you have another question that you want to ask.)